# Convert Blob/Varbinary ti Image in Android

Tags: android, json, string, image, wcf

I have an image being sent to me through web service in JSON format. Here is the snippet of how it looks like : 
{"notif_detailsResult":[{"image":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,....
 I want to dispaly the image on an Imageview in Android. After the parsing the json, I can store the image values in an string

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

String epc = params[0];
String result = null;
String url = "http://192.168.142.1:90/Service1.svc/notif?notif_id=24";
try {

BufferedReader inStream = null;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpR = new HttpGet(url);
httpR.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpR.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpR);
System.out.println("HERE in product display after exectunig response");
inStream = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while((line = inStream.readLine()) != null)
{
sb.append(line + NL) ;   
}
inStream.close();
result = sb.toString();

} catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

super.onPostExecute(result);
try {

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("notif_detailsResult");
JSONObject jObject1 = array.getJSONObject(0);


String data = jObject1.getString("image");
```

Comment: image value is in Base64 string format or byte[] ?

Comment: This is the query I used to insert the image.                     update  dbo.notification
Set image = 
(Select BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
   Bulk 'D:\Steelcase Images\Blue Chair.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)
where notification_id = '24';

Comment: So, I think it is Byte format !

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that-
you have image in "data" variable right?
 so now parse your string into byte []..

```
byte[] outImage=data;//do required thing to parse into byte if needed
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
imgView.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's byte[] then you can get the image value as object.

```
  byte[] b_Image=jsonObject.get("image");       
    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b_Image,0, b_Image.length));
```

Try this one.

Comment: The result I am getting in JSON format is this : {"notif_detailsResult":[{"image":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,....    The above code dosent seem to work :(    Datatype of my image in DB is Varbinary and I used BLOB object to store the image.